# If $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is an integrable function on $B$, do $\int_Af$ exists?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, riemann-integration

Let $A$ and $B$ be open sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $A-B$ has measure zero. If $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is an integrable function on $B$, can we ensure that $\int_Af$ exists?

I am trying show that $\int_Af$ exists, where
$$A=\{(x, y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x>0\text{ and } y>0\}$$
and the function $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is given by
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{(x^2+\sqrt{x})(y^2+\sqrt{y})}.$$
I proved that $\int_Bf$ exists, where
$$B=\{(x, y)\in A: x\neq 1\text{ and } y\neq 1\}.$$
We have that $A-B$ has measure zero, so we can ensure that $\int_Af$ exists?

Comment: What's wrong with $x,y=1$? Did you perhaps mean to write $x\ne 0$ and  $y\ne 0$?

Comment: No. I proved that the integral of $f$ over $(0,1)^2$, $(0,1)\times (1,\infty )$, $(1,\infty )\times (0,1)$ and $(1,\infty)^2$ exists, so the integral over the union of these open sets, B, exists.
I am studying the Analysis on Manifolds by Munkres, and the integral is only defined over bounded sets and open sets. So I can't apply the integral over the set $A-B$.

Comment: The Riemann integral does not exist on an unbounded set whether it is open or not.  On an unbounded open set or a bounded open set and an unbounded function, Munkres defines the extended integral which generalizes improper integrals to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: So you must be concerned about the existence of the extended integral on the set $A-B$. Also it is easier to prove that the extended integral exists on $A$ without even considering $B$.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. You can use that the integral over $A$ is equal to the integral over $A\cap B$ plus the integral of $A\setminus B$ that is zero (and that $f\geq 0$). So $f$ is an integral function over A.

Comment: I am studying the Analysis on Manifolds by Munkres, and the integral is only defined over bounded sets and open sets. So I can't apply the integral over the set $A-B$. Is there another argument without consider the integral over $A-B$?